# What is the best way to normalize and carry a string in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, encoding

I'm collecting textarea data on a form. On the receiving page, I need to store that in a hidden field for POST to a third page for further processing (emailing, save to file, etc.)  I've realized that my shared host has Magic Quotes turned on and that can't be changed-- thus, I am familiar with stripslash() where needed.

Before stuffing the hidden field with say 3 paragraphs of text and mixes with ", ', $, and potentially anything else from any source (Word, RTF, InDesign, who knows)  it of course it's not prepared to be a html field value so I'm thinking run htmlentities() on it. Seems to work well. The form posts and on the 3rd processing page I run a cleaning routine(thin time without the htmlentities() call) mainly to cleanup any MQ generated escaping. Here is my cleaning function with html encode ( have another one w/o that which I run before processing at the end of my task flow)

```
 function cleanHtmlEncodeStrings($str)
 {

       $text = stripslashes( $str );

       // First, replace UTF-8 characters.  (borrowed from a post on the web)
       $text = str_replace(
            array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6"),
            array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
             $text
       );

       // Next, replace their Windows-1252 equivalents.
       $text = str_replace(
            array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133)),
            array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
            $text
      );

      // Next, replace CR & LFs with
      $find = array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\n", "\r", "\R" , "\t", "\x0B");
      $text = str_replace($find, " ", $text );

      $text = htmlentities ($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

      return $text;

 }
```

"Lugubrious Distance is a book about the artist’s feelings of longing for her home state of North Carolina. "Noticing the unnoticed is a running theme in the work I produce. I raise the ordinary to the surface because I find it to be the most honest, vibrant, and beautiful. Beauty is just fine with me."

becomes....

Lugubrious Distance is a book about the artistÃ¢ï¿½ï¿½s feelings of longing for her home state of North Carolina. "Noticing the unnoticed is a running theme in the work I produce. I raise the ordinary to the surface because I find it to be the most honest, vibrant, and beautiful. Beauty is just fine with me."

I have no idea why the ' she is assumed to be entering is not getting caught by my function.

My real question is.... what is the bullet proof way to handle these types of text areas?  I can't possibly account for every odd character that someone will try and enter, so what is the better way?

Thanks!
Rich

[note:  I'm not trying to double post. Rather I'm seeing if I can restate my problem in a more succinct way. So far it's not working :) ]

Comment: Yes, I have considered that. It's just that the inertia archetype for this form and a few others is POST and I didn't want to diverge from that precedent. Maybe it is time to reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

Ever considered to use *[sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)* to keep the data on the server for further processing, instead of moving texts to and fro between server and browser?

Answer (score -1):

I use `base64_encode` / `base64_decode`. Try this:

```
<?
$url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($_POST['text']) {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $text = stripslashes($_POST['text']);
        } else {
            $text = $_POST['text'];
        }
        $escaped = base64_encode($text);
        ?>
        <form action="<?= $url ?>" method="post">
        <p>Hidden data: <i><?= $escaped ?></i></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="encoded" value="<?= $escaped ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Send hidden data">
        </form>
        <?
    } else if ($_POST['encoded']) {
        $decoded = base64_decode($_POST['encoded']);
        ?>
        <p><?= htmlspecialchars($decoded) ?></p>
        <p><a href="<?= $url ?>">Try again</a></p>
        <?
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <form action="<?= $url ?>" method="post">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send source data">
    </form>
    <?
}
?>
```